# How to solve this equation asking for the "average area" of infinitely many triangles?

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Bases $AB$ and $CD$ of trapezoid $ABCD$ are each perpendicular to leg $AD$. If $CD = 6$, $AB = 8$, and $AD = 10$, find the average of the areas of
all noncongruent triangles two of whose vertices are $A$ and $D$ and whose third vertex is a point on $BC$.

**What I tried:** My first thought was to use an integral as a vertex $P$ travels from $C$ to $B$, and find some formula for the area of $\triangle DPA$ in terms of the distance $P$ has traveled. The "noncongruent" part is making it tricky, though; I don't know at what point we're going to start running into triangles we've already covered.

Comment: Is the answer 70? I mean 35.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you will **never** run into triangle you have already covered, as areas of all triangles will be different, as the height changes but base does not!

Also, the area varies linearly from $C $ to $ B$. So you can say the required average is half of the sum of areas of $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle ADB$:

$$A = \dfrac{6\cdot10+8\cdot 10}{2\times2} = 35 \text{ sq. units}$$